# Postman-ом пытаюсь проверить регистрацию на java

Tags: java, spring, postman

Так вот делаю такой запрос

```
{   
"username":"Samir",
"password":"SamirSamir",
"email":"lazali1995@gmail.com",
"first_name":"FIRSTNAME",
"last_name":"LASTNAME",
"roles": [ "ADMIN", "USER"]
```

}
 и получаю ответ такой

```
{
"timestamp": 1545309008185,
"status": 500,
"error": "Internal Server Error",
"exception": "org.springframework.dao.DataIntegrityViolationException",
"message": "could not execute statement; SQL [n/a]; constraint [username]; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: could not execute statement",
"path": "/api/registration/doRegist"
```

}

жалуется на sql поле username, делаю регистрацию пользователя через админку, то есть не используя api все нормально работает, нет неполадок

[image: а вот и сам экзепшн]

может я что то упускаю:)Спасибо всем заранее:)Могу кинуть доп инфу, если есть нужда)

```
public class User extends BaseEntity<Integer> {

public enum Roles {
    ADMIN
}

private String firstName;

private String lastName;
@Column
private String username;

private String email;
private String activationCode;
@JsonProperty(access = Access.WRITE_ONLY)
private String password;


@Convert(converter = StringArrayConverter.class)
private String[] roles;

private Date lastPasswordReset;

private Date dateCreated;
private Date dateUpdated;
private Boolean active;

public User() {
    lastPasswordReset = dateCreated = dateUpdated = new Date();
    roles = new String[0];
    active = true;
}
```

а вот и сама сущность пользователь)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

У Вас, при сохранении пользователя в БД, поле username ==  `null`, отсюда и ошибка.

Проверяйте код, где-то ошибка с присвоением значения полю username.

Comment: нет, решение в другом, я отправлял json, но не делал requestbody)